# Auto populate list items with values from another field or list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a SP2010 standard list that serves as a checklist with 100 items. These items do not change and are fixed other than a few fields that the user changes such as the target data and actual date. One of the columns is named 'Responsibility' and by default is empty. I want this column to feed from another list or field for example: the column will contain the regional director or regional sales person as we have several regions I cannot simply pre-populate the column. What I want is to template this list and then upon deploying get the regional director to enter the names of a) the director and b) the sales person. This would then populate all 100 items 'responsibility' columns and display the actual name of the user instead of job role.
Hope this makes sense

Comment: Sorry I should add that I know I can do this with Workflow but would prefer something instant. Regards

Comment: Ended up using a simple workflow in the end

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a simple workflow in the end as I could not find an alternative option!